# Store an input of multiple lines into a list in python

Tags: python

I have a simple question, I just want to store an input of multiple lines into an array using python, note that the first line of the input is telling me how many lines there will be, so if the first line of the input is 4, the whole input will be of 5 lines in total.

Example:

input:

```
4
1
2
3
4
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I tried using `n = list(map(int, input()))` however when I print the whole list it only stores the first line of the input, and I need all the values.

Thank you.

Comment: How many lines need to be input? Is it 5 everytime you run the program?

Comment: `input()` will be called only once this way, you will need some kind of an explicit loop for this.

Comment: input() will take 1 input each time, after each  new line it is considered as new input, that's why it is taking only 1st input,..... Either take comma or space seperated input rather than each input in new line then split it and use same list(map(int, input().split (',')))

Comment: The integer of the first line tells me how many lines the input will have below that line, so if the first line is 5, that means the input will have 6 lines, I did not considere that as important so I am going to modify my question to be more clear.

Comment: That was also an important input, to solve/explain any problem Don't miss any information for solving the question

Comment: Okay, you do understand that `input()` reads a single line from the standard input, yes? So of course *anything* you do with a single line of input will only process that line of input. You need to come up with a step-by-step process that handles multiple lines of input. Yes? So, think it through logically. What is the first step in this process: you read the first line, and it tells you how many more lines to process. Yes? So implement that. Now that you have that number, do you see how to proceed with the rest of the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension, calling the `input()` function for each iteration, like so:

```
l = [int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))]
```

output for `print(l)`, with the first input being 4:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but note that my program does not know how many lines the input will have until running time, the first line of the input tells me how many lines the total input have plus one (see my question again), I didn't considere that as important so I did not include it on my question, now I've modified it.

Comment: @Tomerikoo What do you think about my answer, is it fine this time ? or it's better to use list comprehension ?

Comment: The input is 4, that means that below that line, there will be 4 lines, so in total, the first line integer + 1 tells me how many lines the total input will have.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer based on comment discussion.

```
num = input()
li = []
for _ in range(num):
    data = int(input())
    li.append(data)

print(li)
```

### input

```
4
6
3
9
4
```

### output

`[ 6 , 3 , 9 , 4 ]`

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine, looping in specific range and appending into a new list the inputs.

```
new_list = []
number_of_loop = int(input())
for _ in range(number_of_loop):
    new_list.append(int(input()))
```

Output of `print(new_list)`, if the `number_of_loop` was 5:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but note that my program does not know how many lines the input will have until running time, the first line of the input tells me how many lines the total input have plus one (see my question again), I didn't considere that as important so I did not include it on my question, now I've modified it.

Comment: @Santiago Updated

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solution is too basic

```
output = []
tot = int(input())
for i in range(tot):
    num=int(input())
    output.append(num)

print(output)
```

If I input `4\n5\n6\n7\n2\n`, I get the output:

```
[5, 6, 7, 2]
```

So, basically the first `input` gets the number of following inputs, and it is used to calculate the range of a `for-loop`, in which, for every iteration, an `input` and a list `append` is performed.

Please note how every `input` is returned in string format and needs to be converted into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

**input()** reads whole single line. You can extend it using **[sys.stdin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin)**.

Now, In your case, each line contains a single integer so there can be two cases:

- **When you are given the number of integers to be read into the list:**
  You can loop through multiple lines and read using **int(input())** and append it to the list.
  (This is the your actual case):

```py
#python 3.x
n = int(input())
ls = []
for i in range(n):
   ls.append(int(input())
```

or

```py
#python 3.x
import sys
n = int(input())
ls = list(map(int,sys.stdin.read().strip().split()))
```

if your input is like this

```
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

then value of **n** and **ls** will be

```
n = 5
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

- **When you are not given the number of integers to be read into the list or don't know the size of list:**

```py
#python 3.x
import sys
ls = list(map(int, sys.stdin.read().strip().split())) #reading whole input from stdin then splitting
```

if your input is like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

then value of **ls** will be

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```